# How do I create a binary variable that is equal to 1 if the date on the column is after 20-4-2020 using lubridate?

Tags: r, lubridate

The last code I tried to use was:

```
nike_airforce$stimulus <- ifelse(dmy(nike_airforce$date) == 20-4-2020, 1, 0)
```

With this code, all the rows get assigned a value of 1. I am trying to assign a value of 1 only to those rows that come after the 20-4-2020 date and zero to the 20-4-2020 date and the dates prior.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow!  Can you run ```dput(head(nike_airforce,10))``` and add that to your question? Knowing the format of your dataframe will help others identify the problem and solution.  Depending on the format on your dataframe, you may need to put 20-4-2020 in quotes (i.e. "20-4-2020") or the ```nike_airforce$date``` variable might not be in date format?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to compare if the date is greater than `"2020-04-20"`, rather than if it's equal. Here a solution using `as.Date`.

```
nike_airforce <- transform(nike_airforce, stimulus=ifelse(as.Date(date, "%d-%m-%Y") > as.Date("2020-04-20"), 1, 0))
nike_airforce
#         date           x stimulus
# 1  18-4-2020 -0.28425292        0
# 2  18-4-2020 -2.44046693        0
# 3  18-4-2020  1.32011335        0
# 4  18-4-2020  1.89519346        0
# 5  18-4-2020  0.46009735        0
# 6  18-4-2020 -0.78445901        0
# 7  18-4-2020 -0.85090759        0
# 8  19-4-2020 -0.30663859        0
# 9  19-4-2020 -0.17191736        0
# 10 19-4-2020  1.21467470        0
# 11 19-4-2020  1.03510352        0
# 12 19-4-2020 -0.60892638        0
# 13 19-4-2020  0.43281803        0
# 14 20-4-2020 -1.71700868        0
# 15 20-4-2020 -2.41420765        0
# 16 21-4-2020 -1.78130843        1
# 17 21-4-2020 -1.76316309        1
# 18 21-4-2020  0.70483734        1
# 19 21-4-2020  0.03612261        1
# 20 21-4-2020 -1.36828104        1
# 21 22-4-2020 -2.65645542        1
# 22 22-4-2020 -0.63999488        1
# 23 22-4-2020  0.20599860        1
# 24 22-4-2020  0.75816324        1
# 25 22-4-2020 -0.72670483        1
# 26 23-4-2020  0.45545012        1
# 27 24-4-2020 -0.43046913        1
# 28 24-4-2020 -0.25726938        1
# 29 24-4-2020  0.50495512        1
# 30 24-4-2020 -0.36105730        1
```

---

*Example data:*

```
nike_airforce <- structure(list(date = c("18-4-2020", "18-4-2020", "18-4-2020", 
"18-4-2020", "18-4-2020", "18-4-2020", "18-4-2020", "19-4-2020", 
"19-4-2020", "19-4-2020", "19-4-2020", "19-4-2020", "19-4-2020", 
"20-4-2020", "20-4-2020", "21-4-2020", "21-4-2020", "21-4-2020", 
"21-4-2020", "21-4-2020", "22-4-2020", "22-4-2020", "22-4-2020", 
"22-4-2020", "22-4-2020", "23-4-2020", "24-4-2020", "24-4-2020", 
"24-4-2020", "24-4-2020"), x = c(-0.284252921416072, -2.44046692857552, 
1.32011334573019, 1.89519346126497, 0.460097354831271, -0.784459008379496, 
-0.850907594176518, -0.306638594078475, -0.171917355759621, 1.2146746991726, 
1.03510352196992, -0.608926375407211, 0.432818025888717, -1.71700867907334, 
-2.41420764994663, -1.78130843398, -1.76316308519478, 0.704837337228819, 
0.0361226068922556, -1.36828104441929, -2.65645542090478, -0.639994875960119, 
0.205998600200254, 0.758163235699517, -0.726704827076575, 0.455450123241219, 
-0.4304691316062, -0.25726938276893, 0.50495512329797, -0.361057298548666
)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```